# Calculate date time difference

Tags: shell

I have 2 variables.

GMDCOM variable stores the date time in below format

```
Tue Oct  1 13:37:38 2013
Tue Oct  1 13:32:40 2013
Tue Oct  1 13:37:53 2013
```

GMDRRS variable stores the date time in the below format

```
Tue Oct  1 13:35:33 2013
Tue Oct  1 13:34:33 2013
Tue Oct  1 13:32:33 2013
```

I want to calculate the datetime difference 
e.g Tue Oct  1 13:37:38 2013 - Tue Oct  1 13:35:33 2013 in hh:mm:ss format 
and store it in another variable. I dont want to use PERL, AWK or SED. Instead i want to use normal BASH Shell commands to achieve it. Please help.

Comment: @fedorqui Ohh, I didn't notice that duplicate from same OP. This should be definitely closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
#!/bin/bash

GMDCOM='Tue Oct  1 13:37:38 2013'
GMDRRS='Tue Oct  1 13:35:33 2013'

d1=$(date -d "$GMDCOM" +%s)
d2=$(date -d "$GMDRRS" +%s)
dd=$(($d1-$d2))

ss=$(($dd%60))
mm=$((($dd/60)%60))
hh=$((($dd/3600)%60))

printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" "$hh" "$mm" "$ss"
```

Comment: When I am trying to run the shell its saying date: illegal option -- d

Comment: I am unable to run the above code. When I am trying to run the shell its saying date: illegal option -- d

Comment: @Tanmoy can you please type `man date` and see if `-d` option shows up. Are you sure you are running this in `bash` ?

Comment: Yah i used man date..It didn't show up the -d option. I am running this in bash only.

Comment: @Tanmoy Sorry to say but in that case either you will have to get **GNU** `date` utility installed or wait for another solution. I thought all `date` utility will have this but it seems this is specific to GNU date. Check this [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) or [bash date](http://www.ss64.com/bash/date.html)

Comment: Where from can i get the upto date `date` utility.?

Comment: Or can u help me in getting the desired output using AWK?

Comment: @Tanmoy not sure about installation. May be you can ask that question on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Tanmoy Sorry to say but I would not prefer deriving `awk` solution when it's pretty easy using `date` utility.